# C# OleDB Save Changes

Tags: c#, oledb, dataadapter

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=\"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New Microsoft Access Database.accdb\"");
                OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT *from pinakas", connection);

                DataTable pinakas_Table = new DataTable();
                DataAdapter.Fill(pinakas_Table);

                MessageBox.Show(pinakas_Table.Rows[1]["Name"].ToString());
```

OK so this line displays the name "George" of my 1st Row of field
"Name".

```
        pinakas_Table.Rows[1]["Name"] = "John";
```

Now this line sets field "Name" the value "John"

```
        pinakas_Table.AcceptChanges();
        DataAdapter.Fill(pinakas_Table);
        MessageBox.Show(pinakas_Table.Rows[1]["Name"].ToString());
```

OK now my app displays the name "John" ! That means the DataTable "pinakas_Table" got the Change.

```
        DataAdapter.Update(pinakas_Table);
```

But it's never saved to my Access database.

Comment: DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
            DataAdapter.Fill(ds); 
            MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["Name"].ToString()); 
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["Name"] = "John";  
            ds.AcceptChanges(); 
            MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["Name"].ToString()); 
            DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]); // Same when i do it with DataSet instead of DataTable. Changes don't commit

Answer (score 0):

[Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/33y2221y.aspx) states...

> Calling `AcceptChanges` on the `DataSet`, `DataTable`, or `DataRow` will cause all `Original` values for a `DataRow` to be overwritten with the `Current` values for the `DataRow`. If the field values that identify the row as unique have been modified, after calling `AcceptChanges` the `Original` values will no longer match the values in the data source. `AcceptChanges` is called automatically for each row during a call to the `Update` method of a `DataAdapter`.

By calling `pinakas_Table.AcceptChanges();` your modified row will be treated as if its data is unchanged from the database, so `DataAdapter.Update(pinakas_Table);` will see no action necessary for that row.  Don't call [`AcceptChanges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges.aspx).  The [`Update` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z1z2bkx2.aspx) will call `AcceptChanges()` for you upon success.

Comment: If i don't  "AcceptChanges" i get Error when i update with DataAdapter.

Comment: {"Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows."}

Comment: Calling `AcceptChanges()` is only suppressing that error because it makes the adapter think there are no updates to perform and it never gets as far as trying to use the unset [`UpdateCommand` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand.aspx).  You need to set `UpdateCommand` and remove the call to `AcceptChanges()`.

Comment: Can't make it save the changes to database ... I'm not even sure that the whole approach is correct... People use "Insert into" Querys. I'm comming from Delphi where all this is easy and now im confsed

Comment: What do you mean by : You need to set UpdateCommand and remove the call to AcceptChanges()

Comment: You need to give the adapter the information it needs to be able to execute an `UPDATE` command, either by setting `DataAdapter.UpdateCommand` or using an [`OleDbCommandBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder.aspx).  You also need to remove the call to `pinakas_Table.AcceptChanges();` (and the second `DataAdapter.Fill(pinakas_Table);` seems unnecessary, too).